# Asp.net core 3.1 with Razor Pages redirects to the Index page instead of the intended page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have the following structure of Razor pages in my project:

[image: My pages structure]

Most of the content is available in the Index page. I am working on my local IIS on the localhost. When I type the localhost address in my browser, the Index page is shown as supposed. However, if I type https://localhost:44352/Logout in order to open the Logout page, it calls the OnGet method of the Index page and opens that page instead of calling the OnGet method of the Logout page.

Here is the OnGet method of the Index page:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("activeModal") != null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Session.GetString("showModalOnGet")) == false && HttpContext.Session.GetString("showModalOnGet") == "true")
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("showModalOnGet", "false");
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("activeModal", "");
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("loginStatusColor", "");
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("loginStatusMessage", "");
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("forgottenPassStatusColor", "");
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("forgottenPassStatusMessage", "");
            }
        }
        await ReloadData();
        
        return null;
    }
```

The code of the Logout OnGet:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        await LogOutUser();
        return RedirectToPage("Index");
    }
```

Both pages have no routing specified after their @page directive. There is nothing specific in their constructors.

Here is the code in the Startup.cs class:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection aServices)
    {
        Log.Information("Configuring Services");

        /// Add caching of the static files
        aServices.AddResponseCaching();

        /// Add support for Razor
        aServices.AddRazorPages();

        aServices.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            /// This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        });

        /// Add the database connection
        string lConnectionString = mEnvironment.IsDevelopment() ? "LocalDB" : "ServerDB";
        aServices.AddDbContext<DB_Spa_WellnessContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(mConfiguration.GetConnectionString(lConnectionString));
        });

        /// Add session to store data
        /// Use memory cache for the session
        aServices.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        aServices.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = ".Spa_Wellness.Session";
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2.0);
        });

        /// Add the configuration of the email client
        aServices.AddSingleton<IEmailConfiguration>(mConfiguration.GetSection("EmailConfiguration").Get<XEmailConfiguration>());

        /// Add the Email Service
        aServices.AddTransient<IEmailService, XEmailService>();

        // Add the configuration of the security service
        aServices.AddSingleton<ISecurityConfiguration>(mConfiguration.GetSection("SecurityConfiguration").Get<XSecurityConfiguration>());

        // Add the Security Service
        aServices.AddTransient<ISecurityService, XSecurityService>();

        /// Add the configuration of the Google Invisible Captcha
        string lCaptchaSection = mEnvironment.IsDevelopment() ? "GoogleInvisibleCaptchaDev" : "GoogleInvisibleCaptcha";
        aServices.AddSingleton<ICaptchaKeys>(mConfiguration.GetSection(lCaptchaSection).Get<XGoogleInvisibleCaptchaKeys>());

        /// Add the service for obtaining user IP and cookies
        aServices.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        aServices.TryAddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();

        /// HTML minification (https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin)
        aServices
            .AddWebMarkupMin(options =>
            {
                options.AllowMinificationInDevelopmentEnvironment = true;
                options.DisablePoweredByHttpHeaders = true;
            })
            .AddHtmlMinification(options =>
            {
                options.MinificationSettings.RemoveOptionalEndTags = false;
                options.MinificationSettings.WhitespaceMinificationMode = WhitespaceMinificationMode.Safe;
            });
        aServices.AddSingleton<IWmmLogger, WmmNullLogger>(); // Used by HTML minifier

        /// Minification with WebOptimizer (https://github.com/ligershark/WebOptimizer)
        aServices.AddWebOptimizer(pipeline =>
        {
            pipeline.MinifyJsFiles();
            pipeline.MinifyCssFiles();
        });
    }

    
    public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        /// Taken from MiniBlog to disable sniffing
        app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Xss-Protection", "1");
            context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
            context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
            context.Response.Headers.Add(
                    "Content-Security-Policy",
                    "form-action 'self'; ");
            /// Cache control
            context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl =
                new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue()
                {
                    Public = true,
                    MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365)
                };
            context.Response.Headers[Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.Vary] =
                new string[] { "Accept-Encoding" };

            return next();
        });

        /// Minification with WebOptimizer (https://github.com/ligershark/WebOptimizer)
        app.UseWebOptimizer();

        /// Always redirect to HTTPS
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        /// Use static files and caching
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
       // app.UseResponseCaching();

        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseSession();

        /// HTML minification (https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin)
        /// TODO: Send web page to the developer
        app.UseWebMarkupMin();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
```

I don't know if there is any other code piece you might be interested.

The other interesting part is that the pages inside ControlPanel folder are shown without any issues. Also the Error and the Privacy pages work fine. The problem seems to be with the newly added pages.

One more thing I noticed. If I am using query strings on the Index page, the results of the query strings are null instead of getting what was typed in the browser.

Forgot to mention that from time to time the Logout page IS opened and its OnGet method is called, but most of the times the Index page is opened.

I have the feeling that something is wrong with my startup configuration, but what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending more time debugging I found what was causing the issue. The following code in the Startup.cs seems to be the problem:

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Xss-Protection", "1");
            context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
            context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
            context.Response.Headers.Add(
                    "Content-Security-Policy",
                    "form-action 'self'; ");
            /// Cache control
            /*context.Response.GetTypedHeaders().CacheControl =
                new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue()
                {
                    Public = true,
                    MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365)
                };
            context.Response.Headers[Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HeaderNames.Vary] =
                new string[] { "Accept-Encoding" };*/

            return next();
        });
```

The last few lines I have commented seem to be causing the issue. After I commented them out everything works fine (for now). I am assuming that some caching here was causing the server to return the Index page instead of the LogOut page.

Anyway, now everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure that the Index page is within the same controller as the OnGetAsync method.
If not, I would recommend to use the `RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller");`.

I hope I helped somewhat.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, the problem still persists. I tried with RedirectToRoute() and also with Response.Redirect() but the problem is still there. Seems like some caching is happening.